# Application crash with android 2.3

Tags: java, android, crash, android-wifi, android-2.3-gingerbread

I use this code to turn off the wifi connection and data connection

```
public static class LowBatteryReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
            wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE); 
            wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
            wifi = (WifiManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

            try {
            ConnectivityManager conman = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            Class<?> conmanClass = Class.forName(conman.getClass().getName());
            Field iConnectivityManagerField = conmanClass.getDeclaredField("mService");
            iConnectivityManagerField.setAccessible(true);
            Object iConnectivityManager = iConnectivityManagerField.get(conman);
            Class<?> iConnectivityManagerClass = Class.forName(iConnectivityManager.getClass().getName());
            Method setMobileDataEnabledMethod = iConnectivityManagerClass.getDeclaredMethod("setMobileDataEnabled", Boolean.TYPE);
            setMobileDataEnabledMethod.setAccessible(true);
            setMobileDataEnabledMethod.invoke(iConnectivityManager, false);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
           }
        }
    }
```

The class will be called in a method to work but this is not important.. I have a nexus 4 with android 4.3 and the code works. Also in android 4.0.3/4, 4.1, 4.1.2, 4.2.1 and .4.2.2.. I use an ActionbarSherlock library so i can use an holo.light anctionbar also with previews android versions. A friend of mine with android 2.3.6 tryied the application and tells me has a crash.. I can't see any logcat for now but i think the problem is the code above. I know that with android 2.3 there was another way to turn the 3g off but i don't know which. How can i detect the android version and make something like : If android >= 4 use the code i posted and if android <=4 use another code (if someone can tell me which is is better thanks).

EDIT:
I found a code for data with android 2.3.. Have i to do something like

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
Method dataConnSwitchmethod;
Class telephonyManagerClass;
Object ITelephonyStub;
Class ITelephonyClass;

TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context
        .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

if(telephonyManager.getDataState() == TelephonyManager.DATA_CONNECTED){
    isEnabled = true;
}else{
    isEnabled = false;  
}   

telephonyManagerClass = Class.forName(telephonyManager.getClass().getName());
Method getITelephonyMethod = telephonyManagerClass.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
getITelephonyMethod.setAccessible(true);
ITelephonyStub = getITelephonyMethod.invoke(telephonyManager);
ITelephonyClass = Class.forName(ITelephonyStub.getClass().getName());

if (isEnabled) {
    dataConnSwitchmethod = ITelephonyClass
            .getDeclaredMethod("disableDataConnectivity");
} else {
    dataConnSwitchmethod = ITelephonyClass
            .getDeclaredMethod("enableDataConnectivity");   
}
dataConnSwitchmethod.setAccessible(true);
dataConnSwitchmethod.invoke(ITelephonyStub);
}
```

so if the version is >= gingerbread this will be the code right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example how to use it:

```
 if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
 // only for gingerbread and newer versions
}
```

Also you can check as below for the version 4>= or <=4 android.

```
 if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 4.0){
        //this code will be executed on devices running on DONUT (NOT ICS) or later
 }
since constant 4 represents donut: public static final int DONUT = 4;
```

You can find out the Android version looking at [Build.VERSION](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html).